# non factors MVC core create dynamic html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, nonfactors-mvc-grid

I am working on asp.net core application and using nonfactors webgrid.

In some scenario I need to create different html tag for `true` and `false` value of model property.

For `true` => any `div` tag

For `false` => any `image` tag

Anybody have any idea regarding this?

Comment: Try an `if` statement maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I use the [NonFactors MVC Grid](https://github.com/NonFactors/MVC6.Grid) frequently, I'm a little confused on your question but I'll answer what I think I read.

Each field can be rendered however you see fit.. when a field is true you could render a div tag with whatever in it, when false an image tag with something else.  Here is an example using that grid (I am using a User model as the example.. so that Model.Users is an IEnumerable of that model):

```
    @(Html
        .Grid(Model.Users)
        .Build(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add(model => model.username).Titled("Username");
            columns.Add(model => model.first_name).Titled("First Name");
            columns.Add(model => model.last_name).Titled("Last Name");
            columns.Add(model => model.last_login).Titled("Last Login").RenderedAs(model => model.last_login == DateTime.MinValue ? "Never" : model.last_login.ToString());
            columns.Add(model => model.banned).Titled("Banned").Encoded(false).RenderedAs(model => model.banned ? "<div>whatever goes here</div>" : "<img />");
        })
        .Filterable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .Css("table table-sm table-striped table-hover table-responsive")
    )
```

Comment: Thanks @b.pell actually i was trying to do same like model.banned if it is bool property.

1 more query: If i need to put some css in div then directly i can put that css class or need to use some other method.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to familarize yourself with [control structures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor#control-structures).